AttributeError: module 'sent2vec' has no attribute 'Sent2VecModel'
i am using colab , this is my code
import sent2vec

sent2vec_model = sent2vec.Sent2vecModel()

and i have this error :
AttributeError

Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-a60edfdfe29c> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Initialiser et entraîner le modèle Sent2Vec
----> 2 sent2vec_model = sent2vec.Sent2vecModel()
      3 sent2vec_model.train(tokenized_names)
      4 

AttributeError: module 'sent2vec' has no attribute 'Sent2vecModel


The title says Sent2VecModel, but the error message says Sent2vecModel (capital V versus lowercase v).  Which is it?

The correct way of installing sent2vec is to clone their repository here https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec and to follow the instructions in the README file
if you install sent2vec using

$ pip install sent2vec

then you'll get the wrong package. Please follow the instructions in the README.md to install it correctly.

